# python threading slower than expected on OCR

Tags: python, multithreading, ocr

I have been trying to read a board from the [2048 game](https://play2048.co/) using modules like cv2 and pytesseract for OCR. The problem with this is OCR seems to be expensive costing roughly 0.2 seconds a tile, with 16 tiles meaning it takes 3.6 to 4.0 seconds to read an entire board.

My solution to this was to use pythons threading module (having had success with it in the past alongside the requests module), creating a thread for each tile (16 threads) and saving the results to a list, however this turned out slower than expected at 2 seconds (which is still half I suppose). However I was expecting it to take no longer than 0.2 to 0.3 seconds as it processes each tile concurrently.

I did try to use the multi-processing module however, this turned out to take even longer (6 seconds) guessing this is due to the initialisation of each process.

Why is it the case that it does not take this expected time? is there something I can do to speed up the process further? thankyou for any response even if a point in the right direction

Comment: (C)Python threading is [limited to running Python code in only one thread concurrently, due to the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Multiprocessing can circumvent that by running the additional instances in their own interpreter, which means that the state has to be replicated in the new instances first. You might try the usual speedups methods like [PyPy](https://pypy.org/), [Cython](https://cython.org/), [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/), or if your code can be vectorized, [numpy](https://www.numpy.org/).

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I am still trying to understand how GIL works, if I understand it right, is it sort of like executing a line of code in one thread (moving on while waiting if it is an I/O operation) and then proceeding to execute another line of code in a different thread before coming back to it later? Also I think the code is mostly optimized I just need some way to optimize the optical character recognition as that is the lengthy part

Comment: The GIL prohibits multiple threads from accessing "shared" objects. If your code is mostly running through "Python code", you will be GIL-limited. If you are locked due to I/O or large calculations outside of Python (i.e. numpy operations), the GIL will not pose any problem. Maybe you can move the actual OCR part to call a C library, if Python is too slow. Have you checked with a profiler which part of the code is the culprit?

Comment: So that is why threading in the case of using the requests module works a lot better since the resources it accesses are not in a shared memory space? and there would be some features in my current project that aren't shared which is what still causes it to execute in half the time. Unfortunately I have never used a profiler before so have no idea where to start with that or any C-libraries I could call